# PHP echo content from <tags>

Tags: php

I've searched around and around and I'm not sure how this really works.

I have the tags

```
<taghere>content</taghere>
```

and i want to pull the "content" so i can put an ifstatement depending on what the "content" is as the "content" is varrying depending on the page

i.e

```
   <taghere>HelloWorld</taghere>

$content = //function that returns the text between <taghere> and </taghere>


if($content == "HelloWorld")
{
    //execute function;
}
else if($content =="Bonjour")
{
    //execute seperate function
}
```

i tried using preg but it doesnt seem to work and just returns whatever value is in the lines field instead of actually giving me the information within the tags

Comment: Where do you set $content?

Comment: sorry, i added a bit more, but the problem im having is -how- to get the $content, which is what is between the two tags

Comment: Yes, but where is this content?  Is it read from an xml feed?  From a webpage that you are crawling?

Comment: ahh, this will be a script in the footer or header that will be on every page, so the the content will be read from whatever is the current page

Comment: I was leaning towards the answer provided, but given this information, it's a silly solution.  It's your server, your control, your headers, so there is no good reason to do what you are saying when you can simply set and read a variable in the header/footer files.  I have a hard time understanding how you wouldn't already know what those are in advance either.

Comment: Stop thinking in terms of header/footer, those are HTML/"web page" terms. If you want to go through the content of the current document, current meaning the one you are _in the process_ of outputting, then you will have to place that part of the script after the last output created, and use output buffering to get it. Although the question would be, why would you need to look up a value that (presumably?) your own script somehow created/output/read from somewhere earlier, again at this point ...? Perhaps you should start familiarizing yourself with the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use DomDocument and loadXML to do this

```
<?php
function doAction($word=""){
$html="<taghere>$word</taghere>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($html);
 //discard white space 
 $hTwo= $doc->getElementsByTagName('taghere'); // here u use your desired tag 
if($hTwo->item(0)->nodeValue== "HelloWorld")
{
    echo "1";
}
else if($hTwo->item(0)->nodeValue== "Bonjour")
{
    echo "2";
    //execute seperate function
}
}
doAction($word="Bonjour");
```

Comment: is there a way to make it so that if <taghere>HelloWorld</taghere> was <taghere>Bonjour</taghere> instead of having to change the value of $html, it will echo 2 instead of 1?

Comment: try it it will do so

Comment: sory I understand you now and I will make it in what you want

Comment: I make it as a function so when you want to change it instead of change the variable value you just call the function with the word you want as a parameter

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the data INSIDE the tag "taghere".

If you are parsing HTML, you should use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Try something similar to this:

```
<?php

// Assuming your content (the html where those tags are found) is available as $html

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your HTML
libxml_clear_errors();

// Note: Tag names are case sensitive

$text = $dom->getElementsByTagName('taghere');

// Echo the content
echo $text
```

Comment: im getting an error here? [ Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on null in /public_html/test.php on line 47 ] i used  basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to grab the current file name and put it in to $html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it like that. Technically it is possible but it's more than an overkill. And you mixed up PHP with HTML in a way that doesn't work.

To achieve the thing that you want you have to do something like this:

```
$content = 'something';
if ($comtent === 'something') {
    //do something
} 
if ($content === 'something else') {
    //do something else
} 

echo '<tag>'. $content . '</tag>' ;
```

Of course you can change `$content` in the ifs.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget, you can allways add an ID into a tag so you can reference it with java script.

```
<tag id='tagid'>blah blah blah </tag>

<script>
document.getElementById(tagid)
</script>
```

This might be a much simpler way to get what you are thinking about then some of the other responses

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what regex you tried and therefor not what would have been wrong. Might have been the escaping of the `<`

```
<?php
     if(preg_match('#\<taghere>(.*)\</taghere>#', $document, $a)){
          $content = $a[1];
     }

?>
```

I  suppose there will be only one